# Horizontal alignment of all popovers on a page

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I have a bootstrap form with various input fields (sometimes multicolumn rows) that should display a popover on focus.

The basic implementation allows me to display a popover next to the input-field. But I would like to display the popover next to the form.

Right now I initialize all my popovers based on the `data-toggle` attribute.

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        'trigger': 'focus'
    });
```

I already tried creating a popover for the form and trigger it with the fields. But when I repositioned the popover with

`$('.popover').css({top: diff});` it would always jump back (because of auto-repositioning).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this, `.popover` already has `position:absolute`, we just gotta push it towards the left; but the arrow is facing towards the outer edge, so we invert the arrow and place it on the left edge of the popover div;

working **snippet below**:

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  'trigger': 'focus',
});
```

```css
.popover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 87% !important;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* .popover .arrow{ display: none;} */

.bs-popover-auto[x-placement^=left]>.arrow,
.bs-popover-left>.arrow {
  right: 0;
  left: -9px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form with custom placement of Popovers</h2>

  <form action="" class="was-validated">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="uname">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If I have two fields in one row, your example does not display any popover for that row. My row looks like> `<div class='form-row'><div class='col'><input ...></div>  <div class='col'><input ...></div></div>`